# Почему кнопка, созданная с помощью tkinter на Python, не принимает указанный размер?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я создаю окно с простой кнопкой с помощью модуля tkinter и указываю ее размер. Если запустить код, появится окно с другим размером. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что не так делаю?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.minsize(300,300)

button = Button(root,
                text = 'Button',
                width=10, height=10)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Вот окно с кнопкой]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно - 10 строк по 10 букв.

Если на кнопке изображение, то размеры считаются в пикселях. Если текст, то в строках и буквах.

Comment: Спасибо, я думал, это ширина и высота в пикселях

Comment: @MAXIM045 если изображение, то в пикселях. Если текст, то в строках и буквах.

Comment: Понял, спасибо:)